# SIM800L module on Arduino nano

Tags: arduino-nano, softwareserial, gsm

I am trying to get Arduino nano and SIM800L module working together. I provided the module with the recommended external voltage of 4.0V (documentation states 3.6V - 4.2V) transformed via LM2596. The original source is 5V 3A.

LED on SIM800L blink once a second as stated in documentation when in an unconnected state.

The schema is the following:

```
                  Antena
                   \_/
                    |
Arduino    SIM800L  |  External 4.0V
             NET ---/
             VCC ----- +4.0V
D2 --------- RST
D3 --------- RX
D4 --------- TX
             GND ----- GND
```

I have already tried 3 different libraries for AT communication and also sending raw AT commands using writing to serial manually. I also tried another SIM800L module because I thought the module is faulty.

Here is the dump from serial communication:

```
[551135] ### TinyGSM Version: 0.10.9
[551139] ### TinyGSM Compiled Module:  TinyGsmClientSIM800
AT
��AT
�AT
H�j���[552012] ### Unhandled: Hj
AT
AT-���[552317] ### Unhandled: AT-
AT
��AT
��AT
�Z5
[553228] ### Unhandled: Z5
AT
␚)O���[553532] ### Unhandled: ␚)O
AT
AT���[553836] ### Unhandled: AT
AT
��AT
��AT
�)OK��[554748] ### Unhandled: )OK
AT
���[555053] ### Unhandled: 5
AT
���AT
��AT
��AT
�j�H�[556266] ### Unhandled: jH
AT
CC����[556570] ### Unhandled: CC
AT
AT���[556875] ### Unhandled: AT
AT
��AT
AT
���[557787] ### Unhandled: T
AT
�H����[558091] ### Unhandled: H
AT
AT���[558395] ### Unhandled: AT
AT
��AT
��AT
AT
jRO���[559610] ### Unhandled: jRO
AT
AT���[559915] ### Unhandled: AT
AT
��AT
��AT
AT
�
OK��[561128] ### Unhandled: OK
Failed to initialize SIM800L
```

As you can see the module is trying to negotiate the baudrate. By default, I use speed 9600 as stated in the documentation. When I use a different baudrate the module does not respond at all.

It seems the module replies and sometimes even correctly. Response to `AT` command should be `OK`.

Do you know how do I successfully negotiate the speed and establish reliable serial communication with the module? Do I miss any electrical components in my circuit like a capacitor or resistor? I tried to use capacitor 35V / 3300µF but without any difference. I think my power source is strong enough.

The source code is the following:

```cpp
#define PIN_GSM_RST             2
#define PIN_GSM_TX              3
#define PIN_GSM_RX              4
#define GSM_BAUDRATE            9600

#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800
#define TINY_GSM_DEBUG          Serial
#define TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS       true
#define TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI       false

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <StreamDebugger.h>

SoftwareSerial serial_SIM800L(PIN_GSM_RX, PIN_GSM_TX);
StreamDebugger debugger(serial_SIM800L, Serial);
TinyGsm modem(debugger);
TinyGsmClient client(modem);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(1000);

    Serial.println(F("Serial initialized"));

    serial_SIM800L.begin(GSM_BAUDRATE);
    delay(5000);

    while (!modem.init()) {
        Serial.println("Failed to initialize SIM800L");
    }
}

void loop() {
    //
}
```

Comment: Did you connect the GND of the Arduino with the GND of the SIM800L? I can not see a connection in the schematics.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer No, I only connected the SIM800L to the ground of the external source. Might that be the problem?

Comment: Of cause; All voltages that come from the arduino to the SIM800L must have a reference GND. You need a common potential. If you have none the Arduino is not able to communicate with the module. The GND of all modules and external Powersuplies must be connected. Only if you use a separate circuit, eg. behind a relais, the GND must not be connected.

Comment: One additional thing. The Nano is usally  a 5 Volt board. Are you sure the SIM800L pins are 5 Volt tolerant. If you connect GND, they might be faced by 5V. That could kill them, if they are not 5V tolerant.

Comment: Max working voltage of SIM800L is 4.2V. If the voltage is higher than 4.4V the module turns off. What schema to use so the module is not exposed to 5V via GND then?

Comment: Probably level shifter; or if you have a 3.3 Volt controller (Arduino Due, Micro, 3.3V Nano). As you are not familiar with electronics (I assume), search for arduino projects with SIM800L in the internet. And don't trust all the videos that say it is save to use a SIM 800L with 5V Arduinos. The following might be interesting for you: https://lastminuteengineers.com/sim800l-gsm-module-arduino-tutorial/

Comment: I used LM2596 to convert 5V to 4V eventually. I tried resistor level shifter as well before. Many articles I found simply did not use external power but diode voltage drop so board 5V pin could be used and I did not realize that. Your suggestion of connecting GNDs worked. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Just to mention it: The Arduino pins that are connected to the SIM Module are 5 Volts. If your Module version has internal protection for these pins, all is fine. But, if the pins are connected without level shifting, the Module might work for a time, but there is a hight possibility that it get's destroyed. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @PeterPaulKiefer here is the answer.

External power for SIM800L module GND pin needs to be connected to both SIM800L module GND pin and Arduino nano GND pin. (e.g between RST and R2 pin on Arduino nano)

In order for the calling function to work, you also need to use a capacitor on SIM800L VCC and GND pins. I used 35V, 3300µF.

Schema:

```
                  Antena
                   \_/
                    |
Arduino    SIM800L  |  External 4.0V
             NET ---/
             VCC ----- +4.0V
 D2 --------- RST   |
 D3 ---------  RX  === Capacitor (35V, 3300µF)
 D4 ---------  TX   |
GND --------- GND ----- GND
```